# What is trident's persistentAggregate equivalent in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Say I have this trident job:

```
TridentState wordCounts =
      topology.newStream("spout1", spout)
        .each(new Fields("sentence"), new Split(), new Fields("word"))
        .groupBy(new Fields("word"))
        .persistentAggregate(
            MemcachedState.opaque(serverLocations),
            new Count(),
            new Fields("count")
        )
```

How would I achieve the same thing in Spark Streaming? I looked at `updateStateByKey` but this seemed to keep the state internally (as opposed to keeping it on external state like Memcached) & indefinitely. It also looks like it tries to dump everything on each batch when I save it with e.g. `saveAsTextFile` as opposed to emitting only key-values that were updated on that batch.

I know I could simply interact with an external state with `foreachRDD`, but in that case, how would I make sure I process a record exactly once?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Trident, but I could help with Spark Streaming. Could you explain some more what do you require?

Comment: @maasg: Thanks! I've researched about this and think I know the answer. I added it as an answer to this question, maybe you can check if my understanding is correct if you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

After some researching, this is what I found:

- Spark Streaming only supports at-least-once semantics for output operations, so it can't provide the exactly-once semantics of Trident (at least without writing code that does it yourself).
- `updateStateByKey` *can* provide exactly-once semantics, but this relies on the fact that it's output completely replaces the previous output (it emits the whole state on each checkpointing). This makes it unusable for any non-significant amount of state. In addition, there is no way to initialize the state with existing data. If you relaunch the job, the state will reset (at least that's my understanding). There are plans to add this functionality in 1.3.0.

In conclusion, if you want transactional update going with Trident seems to be the safe bet.